# AFUI list dynamically created list element doesn't let me have click events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, appframework

I am trying to attach a click handler to an element that I create dynamically and add to an li element. When I try to attach it to the li element it doesn't work. But when I try to add it to a higher level div or even the ul element then the click handler works.

This doesn't give me my click event:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.setAttribute('class','list');
main_div.appendChild(ul);

var li = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);

var checkbox = document.createElement('div');
checkbox.setAttribute('class','checkBtn-unselected');
checkbox.onclick = function(){alert('foo');};
li.appendChild(checkbox);
```

This does give me my click event:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.setAttribute('class','list');
main_div.appendChild(ul);

var li = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);

var checkbox = document.createElement('div');
checkbox.setAttribute('class','checkBtn-unselected');
checkbox.onclick = function(){alert('foo');};
ul.appendChild(checkbox);
```

I am using intel's App framework/UI as well. I don't know if that may have anything to do with it. Also, in other places I have been able to just write HTML and place my checkbox in it and it seems to work. This is only when I try to create it dynamically does the event handler not run.

Answer (score 0):

your code is good, but the height of checkbox DIV is `0` so your click is not fired, the `li` has a padding of `20px`. I added this and click works:

```
checkbox.style.height = "40px";
```

Here is full code: http://jsbin.com/moqoge/7/edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that next to my checkbox I had a label. The padding of the label (which had some relative positioning fuzziness) overlapped my button and was intercepting the touch/click events. I changed the css of the label so it didn't overlap my button and now it's working.